# mongoose schema create empty array by default?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im new to mongoose and mongoDB, by a tutorial, I have a user schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            index: {
                unique: true,
                dropDups: true
            }
        },
        password: String,
        displayName: String,
        avatar: {
            type: String,
            default: "./img/user.png"
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        },
        ask_history: [
            {
                question_id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questionAnswer'
                },
                favorite: Boolean,
                ask_time: Date
            }
        ],
        interest: [String]
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        displayName: String,
        avatar: String,
        familyName: String,
        givenName: String,
        gender: String,
        ageMin: Number,
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        },
        ask_history: [
            {
                question_id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questionAnswer'
                },
                favorite: Boolean,
                ask_time: Date
            }
        ],
        interest: [String]
    },
    twitter: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        avatar: String,
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        },
        ask_history: [
            {
                question_id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questionAnswer'
                },
                favorite: Boolean,
                ask_time: Date
            }
        ],
        interest: [String]
    }
}, {strict: true});
```

It creates user record by the way user is sign up for, either give local email or using oauth register by 3rd party.

Schema above will generate a document looks like this if I create a local user:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58792ee6e8a08204a0d68f7a"
    },
    "twitter": {                  ////////////////////////////////////////
        "interest": [],           //
        "ask_history": [],        //
        "role": "student"         //
    },                            // <-- nothing should created for a local user
    "facebook": {                 //
        "interest": [],           //
        "ask_history": [],        //
        "role": "student"         //
    },                            ////////////////////////////////////////
    "local": {
        "password": "$2a$10$OtdbF7t52TyNAuwZXFT0u.Q/A.E5TeV4T.shHCxSSxDll2nX4bCbW",
        "displayName": "aaa",
        "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "interest": [],
        "ask_history": [],
        "role": "admin",
        "avatar": "./img/user.png"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

The problem I'm having is at

```
ask_history: [
            {
                question_id: {
                    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'questionAnswer'
                },
                favorite: Boolean,
                ask_time: Date
            }
        ],
interest: [String]
```

With out those array declaration in the schema the document looks just fine for any type of the user, for example, a local user, document would looks like this (no facebook or twitter field):

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    local: {
        email: {
            type: String,
            index: {
                unique: true,
                dropDups: true
            }
        },
        password: String,
        displayName: String,
        avatar: {
            type: String,
            default: "./img/user.png"
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        }
    },
    facebook: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        displayName: String,
        avatar: String,
        familyName: String,
        givenName: String,
        gender: String,
        ageMin: Number,
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        }
    },
    twitter: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        email: String,
        name: String,
        avatar: String,
        role: {
            type: String,
            default: "student"
        }
    }
}, {strict: true});
```

---

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5874d1d0cd045371b4e96eca"
    },
    "local": {
        "password": "$2a$10$KpnIE2Uc2tX.YfcQCGm6EeDMexFFZXbKJVcQvxltBxrTkxb8E7mH.",
        "displayName": "aaa",
        "avatar": "./img/user.png",
        "email": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "role": "admin"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And this is my function for creating a local user:

```
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true 
}, function(req, email, password, done) {
    if (!req.body.name || req.body.name.length == 0) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Name can\'t be empty'));
    }
    User.findOne({
        'local.email': email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Error: ' + err));
        } else {
            if (validator.validate(email)) {
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email already registered.')); 
                } else {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.local.email = email;
                    newUser.hashPassword(password);
                    newUser.local.displayName = req.body.name;
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'Email not vaild'));
            }
        }
    });
}));
```

My question is how can I set the schema to when the document is created, the array will not be created.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You say something about multiple creation of record, but what I see is that inside the same document (record in a relational database) Mongoose is adding empty arrays and default values.

Comment: Hi! Please post a full example, with JS code, and explain which code generates the good result in Mongo, and which code change generates the bad one.

Comment: @AntonioVal Hi, I changed the title, sorry for being misleading, I guess the problem is adding array declaration in the schema will cause document generate empty filed even nothing was past during the creation.

Comment: @VladFr Hi I have update both the issue schema and working schema and function code for creating a document.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your exact question the answer would be:

> Arrays are special because they implicitly have a default value of [] (empty array).

```
const ToyBox = mongoose.model('ToyBox', ToyBoxSchema);
console.log((new ToyBox()).toys); // []
```

> To overwrite this default, you need to set the default value to undefined

```
const ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
  toys: {
    type: [ToySchema],
    default: undefined
  }
});
```

This is from the [mongoose v6.4.4 docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) but as I checked the

But on the other hand maybe you should create a schema for your `subdocuments` and set the `default` value for them to `undefined`. That would also do the trick and would be more exact definition.

```
app: {
    type: AppDataSchema, // AppDataSchema is a schema defined elsewhere
    default: undefined,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty array, you need to use  `default: null`.
If you use `undefined` instead, the schema will not create the array at all because `undefined` is not a value but `null` is.

Try this:

```
const ToyBoxSchema = new Schema({
  toys: {
    type: [ToySchema],
    default: null
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: I have added an explanation. Is it clear now?